# Objective-C | Take properties and protocols declared and implemented from .m and expose publicly in .h interface

Tags: objective-c, properties, interface, protocols, implementation

I need to refactor an existing code to have certain behavior. In order to achieve that I'd have to take some properties declared inside of the interface block in the .m file and pass it to the .h file (for accessing it publicly from other classes). Also, there are some methods declared and implemented in the .m file that I'd have to declare in the .h file.

Are there any issues in doing this?

Finally, some of those methods make use of a protocol declared and implemented in the .m file.

Can I take this protocol, put it in its own protocol file, and make use of it with an `import <blabla.h>` statement?
In case I can do this, does this .h file need to have the according .m implementation file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• No need to create an `.m` file for a protocol since there's no implementation. Once you did that you can move the code to the new `.h` file and import it using `import "file.h"` and **not** `<file.h>`, this is reserved for frameworks.

• Moving properties from `.h` to `.m` file should definitely not be a problem.

• The other way around might produce some compile time errors - **You have to make sure non of these properties is accessed outside of the `.m` file.** The compiler will let you know once you make the change and try to build your project.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm really new to objective-c, just a few weeks. I need to refactor an existing code to have certain behavior. In order to achieve that I'd have to take some properties declared inside of the interface block in the .m file and pass it to the .h file (for accessing it publicly from other classes). Also, there are some methods declared and implemented in the .m file that I'd have to declare in the .h file.

In most cases there should be no problems with moving the property declarations from the extension to the interface in the header. The only difference should be scope. For the methods in the .m, just add a declaration to the .h and they'll be available to whatever imports it.

> Finally, some of those methods make use of a protocol declared and
>   implemented in the .m file.
>
> Can I take this protocol, put it in its own protocol file, and make
>   use of it with an import statement? In case I can do this, does this
>   .h file need to have the according .m implementation file?

You can just take the protocol definition and move it to a header file. It doesn't need a .m. Anything that needs to implement the protocol can import the .h and implement whatever is required to conform in their own .m. If the only classes that need to know about the protocol are ones that would import the .h of the class the .m with the protocol currently belongs  to, you could also just move the protocol from the .m to that class's .h rather than make a separate .h for it.